# Jira pre-receive hook on GitHub server not working for git commit pushes

Tags: regex, git, github, jira, githooks

i just added the https://github.com/github/platform-samples/blob/master/pre-receive-hooks/require-jira-issue.sh

script to one of my github remote repos and was able to successfully configure a pre-receive hook at the org level and enabled it for one of my sample repos. Now when i push to that sample repo from local, it always results in the below error :-

```
remote: jira-commit-hook.sh: failed with exit status 1
remote: grep: Invalid range end
remote: ERROR
remote: ERROR: Your push was rejected because the commit
remote: ERROR: e9b0dd4695a51beb51e6fc1a8d16f01fa7dd13b8 in master
remote: ERROR: is missing the JIRA Issue
remote: ERROR:
remote: ERROR: Please fix the commit message and push again.
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://************'
```

The commit regex I'm using is `msg_regex='[DST\-[0-9]+\]'` since DST is the project key in our jira for one of the projects. All the commits i am pushing has the string `DST-***` in their message where `***` is a number and `DST-***` is some actual issue key for the jira project here. Any idea why the remote server hook is rejecting the push. Looks like its not validating the regex. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-` is a special character in regex when you use inside character class `[]`, it stands for range when it appears anywhere else except

- As the first character in class or after `[^]`
- At the end of character class

so your regex should be

`DST-[0-9]+`

[`Character Class`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

Comment: Thanks! so msg_regex='DST-[0-9]+' is working for me for any commit message that has DST-somenumber no matter where this string is placed in the message. What should i do if i need similar thing for other strings like DEMO-*** , AMI-
***, KAE-***. How should i add these under same regex so that means if the commit message has anyone of these it should apply. i suppose it should be something like msg_regex='DST-[0-9]+|DEMO-[0-9]+|AMI-[0-9]+|KAE-[0-9]+'  Please suggest

Comment: @Ashley you can  use `(?:Demo|AMI|KAE)-[0-9]+`

Comment: Thanks Code Maniac. That's a much simplified expression and works for me.

Comment: - Looks like msg_regex='(?:DEMO|AMI|KAE)-[0-9]+' worked for me for a while for different commit messages and then stopped for some reason. But msg_regex='DEMO-[0-9]+|AMI-[0-9]+|KAE-[0-9]+' works for me always. Not sure why that would be, but all i want here is that whenever i enter any of these anywhere in the message:- DEMO-*** , AMI-***, KAE-*** where *** is any postive integer, it should work and let me allow push my commits.Looks like (?:Demo|AMI|KAE)-[0-9]+ is invalidating certain use cases or may be i'm wrong.

Comment: @Ashley i mistakenly typed `Demo` instead of all capital `DEMO` :p, just change to `(?:DEMO|AMI|KAE)-[0-9]+`

Answer (score 1):

My guess based on your original expression,

```
[DST\-[0-9]+\]
```

is that maybe the desired expression would be

```
\[DST-[0-9]+\]
```

or maybe just,

```
DST-[0-9]+
```

not sure though. I'm positive that you may not need to escape the `-` in this case, since it is not in a char class, `-` is only a metachar inside a char class `[]`.